# ApexCharts barchart vertical categories logic in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apex, apexcharts

I am having a problem trying to figure out how to display the correct data to the correct category.
My data is in this format from a json API:

```
{
  "name" : "product1",
  "records": "5",
  "month" : "Jan",
},
{
  "name" : "product1",
  "records": "10",
  "month" : "Feb",
},
{
  "name" : "product1",
  "records": "20",
  "month" : "March",
},
{
  "name" : "product2",
  "records": "5",
  "month" : "Feb",
}
```

an example of the data model.

```
this.state = {
  barChart: { 
   options: {
      plotOptions: {
        xaxis: {
          categories: []
       }}}
        series: [{name: [], data: []}}
```

This is the state in ReactJs from apexcharts
I've been spending couple of days and I've tried to sort it based on alphabet: which the data was wrong displayed in the graph.
I was reading the documentation but didn't figure out how to do, or how to get the logic right. the categories cannot repeat so: [Jan, Feb, March]
and the data[records] has to be correct in it's own category.

Comment: So what are the categories of you x and y axises? Are your trying to create a time-series?

Comment: Categories of my x-axis are month names and y-axises are series:[data] number of records. Yes I am, the logic of the chart is from the basic barchart[apexcharts]

Comment: Gotcha, so are you thinking about creating something like a stacked-barchart or a line-chart where each line is its own product? It looks like you'll need more than one-series object.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo just a basic one, a stacked-barchart, like this: https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/column-charts/basic/, I do have more then one-series object.. as you can see from the json model, there are two products but one of them has data for [jan,feb,march] and other for [feb] just.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo appreciate, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193875/discussion-between-christopher-ngo-and-michael).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will create a series object for each Product. Each Product will have its own data array. Where each number corresponds sequentially to a month. A 0 value is added in place for a month that was not utilized in the data-set for that product.

### Example dataset:

```
let data = [{
  "name" : "product1",
  "records": "5",
  "month" : "Jan",
},
{
  "name" : "product1",
  "records": "10",
  "month" : "Feb",
},
{
  "name" : "product1",
  "records": "20",
  "month" : "Mar",
},
{
  "name" : "product2",
  "records": "5",
  "month" : "Feb",
},
{
  "name" : "product1",
  "records": "5",
  "month" : "May",
},
{
  "name" : "product2",
  "records": "5",
  "month" : "Jun",
}
]
```

This creates an array of months that were used in the data-set. No duplicates. We will use it to map the corresponding data-values of each product in their specific month.

### Creating Categories:

```
let months = data.map((item) => item.month).filter((item, index, array) => array.indexOf(item) == index)
```

### Creating Series:

```
const productTotals = data.reduce((obj, curr) => {
    if(!obj[curr.name]){
        obj[curr.name] = []
    }

    obj[curr.name][months.indexOf(curr.month)] = parseInt(curr.records)
    return obj
}, {})

const series = Object.entries(productTotals).map(([name, prodArr]) => {
    return {
        name: name,
        data: months.map((month, monthIndex) => {
            if(!prodArr[monthIndex]){
                return 0
            } else {
                return prodArr[monthIndex]
            }

        })
    }

})
```

Then simply update the properties with your new series data and categories.

```
this.state = {
  barChart: { 
   options: {
      plotOptions: {
        xaxis: {
          categories: [...months]
       }}}
        series: [...series]}
```

Comment: you are a legend, is working perfectly fine. if any questions will have in the future will let you know.

Comment: @Michael thanks :)! This was a great problem so I'm glad to help!

Comment: Hi @Christopher, still working on the project with the graphs, data grids and I am trying to solve a problem.. what is the best way to contact you to ask you couple of questions?

Comment: Hi @Michael, that's awesome man, I hope the project is coming along nicely. You can reach me through email if you'd like: ChristopherNgo94@gmail.com   Shoot me your questions and I'll see if I can assist :)

Comment: Hi @Christopher, I emailed you a question. Thanks