# unable to retrieve the values from the specific thing

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I'm new to the apexchart and reactjs, don't know how to display *series* based on the no. of messages of a particular month instead of giving static data. I've gone through this link "[ApexCharts barchart vertical categories logic in ReactJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288819/apexcharts-barchart-vertical-categories-logic-in-reactjs)" but unable to put the logic correctly.

***This is the Code***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";
import { messages } from "../constants/constant";
class Donut extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        // Setting the response
        // this.props.setMessages(messages);
        // this.props.stareMessages();
        console.log("messages", messages);
        this.setState({
          messages: messages
        });
      });
  }
  state = {
    index: 0,
    flag: false,
    messages: [],
    options: {
      labels: [
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December"
      ],

      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: "bar",
        events: {
          dataPointSelection: (event, chartContext, config) => {
            this.setState({
              labels: chartContext.opts.labels,
              percentage: chartContext.opts.series
            });
            const selectedData = messages.find(
              x => x.id === config.dataPointIndex + 1
            );
            this.setState({ flag: true, selectedData });
          }
        }
      },

      legend: {
        position: "bottom",
        horizontalAlign: "center"
      }
    },
    series: [44, 55, 41, 17, 15, 50, 79, 46, 78, 96, 78, 100]
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedData, options, series } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="donut">
        <Chart options={options} series={series} type="donut" width="380" />

        {selectedData && (
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th width="200">From</th>
                <th width="200">To</th>
                <th width="200">Date & Time</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{selectedData.from}</td>
                <td>{selectedData.to}</td>
                <td>{selectedData.date}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Donut;
```

Comment: Is this what your are trying to achieve https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-chatterjee-swr90 ?

Comment: @MikeRos - Yes, Thanks a lot for helping me. It is working fine :)

Comment: np chandan, i will edit the answer according to ^^ codesandbox

Comment: @MikeRos - Hi Mike, I have a query in the code, there are static values in *series* (line no. 55), can we make it similar like  *label*. I mean in a dynamic way?

Comment: What do you mean? In componentDidMount we update state to show new values (from your fetch).

Comment: @MikeRos - Thank you, now i got it. In table, can we display number of emails according to the respective month. I mean if we have 2 messages in January month. Then it will display list in the table (2 rows). Can we display the percentage in the table instead of **from** in the table?

Comment: Since this question has beed answered, lets move this conversation to chatroom ( https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200743/apex-charts )

Comment: Here you go  https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-ives-cfyts

Comment: You're awesome :)... Thanks a lot, It's working Great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use momentjs to parse your date format.

I'm pretty sure it can be optimized. I'd say the best optimization is to already receive the data in correct format.

```
const countEmailsByMonth = data => {
  const dates = data.map(datum =>
    moment(datum.date, ["DD-MM-YYYY"]).format("MMMM")
  );

  // getting our dates from your message json file 
  //and formatting them to display month

  const months = moment.months();
  // getting 12 months arr from moment.js

  const mergedMonths = [...months, ...dates];
  // merging months and dates together

  const sortedMonths = mergedMonths.sort(
    (a, b) => months.indexOf(a) - months.indexOf(b)
  );
  //sorting months
  const chartData = {};
  //counting duplicates
  sortedMonths.map(val => (chartData[val] = chartData[val] + 1 || 0));
  return chartData;
};
```

here is link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-chatterjee-swr90)

Comment: Hi, in my code, I 've used constant.js file and the respective file i'm using for inblx component also. Based on the date, it should calculate series (no.of dates of a particular month)

Comment: If i understood correctly, your data consists of unsorted messages and you want sort those messages by date (or month) and display in the graph (ex, label: January, series: 60 msgs).

Comment: Yes, you're correct... Label: month and series: no of emails in a peraticular month depending on the date

Comment: I see, so you have troubles with counting emails by month?